# XamFormsExtended / Xfx.Controls won't allow formatting numbers

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I inherited a project that uses the Xamarin Extended Forms controls. All of the text boxes on the form use this. I am trying to do something that feels very simple... I want to display and capture numbers and display them with thousands seperators.  So, my odometer field displays 356,098 instead of 356098, much easier to read. It needs to save the integer without formatting in the binding.

I've tried various forms of string formatting on the text box and when my page loads I get an endless loop. It seems like the control formats the field and updates it which triggers the getter/setter which then tries to format it without the comma which triggers the textbox that there is a change, through the binding, and it adds the comma, which triggers another loop and on and on.

Here is the control.

```
<xfx:XfxEntry 
    Text="{Binding OdometerEntry, StringFormat='{0:N0}'}"  
    TextColor="{Binding TextColor}" 
    IsEnabled="{Binding READ_ONLY, Converter={StaticResource NegateBool}}"
    FontSize="Medium"
    Keyboard="Numeric"
    Margin="10,-20,0,-20" 
    Grid.Row="2" 
    Grid.Column="1" />
```

And here is the model for that field:

```
public string OdometerEntry
{
    get => _odometerEntry;
    set
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) || value == "0")
        {
            if (Inspection != null && Inspection.Truck != null)
            {
                Inspection.Truck.OdometerEntry = 0;
            }

            _odometerEntry = "";
        }
        else
        {
            int i = General.IntParseSafe(value);
            if (i < 0)
            {
                i = 0;
            }

            if (Inspection != null && Inspection.Truck != null)
            {
                Inspection.Truck.OdometerEntry = i;
            }

            _odometerEntry = i.ToString();
        }

        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

I tried adding formatting in the ToString but that did not work. I realize this form extender is no longer supported, but I'm hoping someone has some insight.

**UPDATE**

I tried using the regular Entry tag but same result. The string just will not format.

```
<Entry Text="{Binding OdometerEntry,StringFormat='{0:#,0}'}"
```

Comment: See following : https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/numeric-entry/number-formatting

Comment: Shouldn’t OdometerEntry be a numeric type, not string?

Comment: We're not using Syncfusion so not sure how that applies. I have Numeric specified for the keyboard of the input. The value should be passed as a number but displayed as text in order to display commas?

Comment: It isn't meaningful to `StringFormat` a field that user is typing in. (Only use on readonly fields such as Labels). Instead, do the formatting **programmatically** by overriding `OnTextChanged`. There, you can keep track SEPARATELY of the displayed string and the underlying numeric value. You update the displayed string as needed. You have to program it carefully to not cause an infinite loop. An alternative solution is to have user type into one field, and show the formatted result in a separate field.

Answer (score 0):

Rough sketch of the solution, off the top of my head:

```cs
int _numericValue;
string _previousString = "";

override OnTextChanged(...)
{
    string newText = ...;   // From a parameter to OnTextChanged.
    if (string.Equals(newText, _previousString))
        return;   // Avoid infinite loop - this call caused by our change!

    string formattedString = StringFormat("...", newText);   // Apply desired format.
    if (!string.Equals(formattedString, _previousString))
    {
        _previousString = formattedString;
        // CAUTION: This triggers another call to `OnTextChanged`.
        theTextField.Text = formattedString;
        // TODO: Set cursor to end of text?
    }
}
```